# How to include external au3 (AutoIt) files to Ruby?

Tags: ruby, include, pixel, autoit, win32ole

I'm calling AutoItX through Ruby WIN32OLE to do some automation in windows and came across a scenario where I had to get the pixel color from the screen and show the color in a msg box. Autoit doesn't have the msgbox method built-in, so this has to be done by including an external file.

This works fine in Autoit as shown below:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Local $iColor = PixelGetColor(10, 100)

MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "The decimal color is: " & $iColor)
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "The hex color is: " & Hex($iColor, 6))
```

Since I'm calling AutoItX methods from Ruby it can't be included the same way as above.

Here is my ruby script for opening an android emulator. I'm planning on using pixel search / image search to identify apps and send mouse clicks to interact with them.

```
require 'win32ole'

# create autoit object from win32ole
puts 'Creating oAutoIt Object...'
oAutoIt = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")

# open MEmu
puts 'Opening MEmu'
MEmu_pid = oAutoIt.Run "C:/Program Files/Microvirt/MEmu/MEmu.exe", "", oAutoIt.SW_SHOWNORMAL
#MEmu_pid = oAutoIt.RunWait "C:/Program Files/Microvirt/MEmu/MEmu.exe", "", oAutoIt.SW_SHOWNORMAL # => pauses the script waits for MEmu to finish.
puts "MEmu is running | PID #{MEmu_pid}"
```

What I need to do is to include external AutoIt functions to the current script.
I would like to proceed in a standard way (planning on scaling later). So how do I go about including au3 files into my ruby script?

Comment: PixelGetColor is a standard AutoIT function. oAutoIt.PixelGetColor(10,100) should work

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question since and now it clearly identifies my need of an external file for a msg box.

Answer (score 1):

MsgBox() isn't available in AutoItX, but you could call the MessageBox function directly from Ruby instead.

MessageBox API documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx